# How do I know whether a container in kubernetes is initiated by a yaml file or a (out of the box)docker image in Openshift?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am assigned to a new project and the engineer who deployed some applications has already left the project and company now I need to troubleshoot all the issues. The application is down and I am trying to replicate the issue on another instance however I am not able to figure out how was the application been deployed ? I am new to docker and Kubernetes.